# Atiyah and MacDonald Theorem 9.5

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

$K$ is an algebraic number field, $A$ its ring of integers. Theorem 5.17 shows that $A\subseteq\sum\mathbb{Z}v_j$ with $v_j\in K$. Theorem 9.5 then concludes that $A$ is a f.g. $\mathbb{Z}$-module. I can't quite see this last step.

Comment: Do you know the basic properties of finitely generated modules over a PID (here, $\mathbb Z$) ? Such as the fact that any finitely generated torsionfree module is free, and that any submodule of a finitely generated free module is finitely generated free?

Comment: If this machinery was what A & M had in mind, surely they would have said so?

Comment: OK, here is an argument more in the A&M style: Since $A$ is a submodule of the finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module $\sum \mathbb Z v_j$, it must itself be finitely generated (since $\mathbb Z$ is noetherian).

Comment: That's great thanks! (I had got as far as thinking about a sub-module of $\sum\mathbb{Z}v_j$ but missed using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ was Noetherian.)